# ansible commands takes forever to execute

Tags: python3, ansible

I installed ansible with pip on python 3.6.8  virtual environment
everything works fine , but occasionally all ansible commands takes a very very long time to get executed, but then consecutive execution of same commands are instantaneous, but to be seen again in some time

i dont see any errors on the terminal or /var/log/messages
system is load is also negligible, what am i missing here ?

```
(env1) [centos@linux1 ~]$ time ansible --version
ansible 2.8.0
  config file = /home/centos/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/centos/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/centos/env1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/centos/env1/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]

real    7m37.920s
user    0m1.719s
sys     0m0.088s


(env1) [centos@linux1 ~]$ time ansible --version
ansible 2.8.0
  config file = /home/centos/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/centos/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/centos/env1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/centos/env1/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]

real    0m1.660s
user    0m1.564s
sys     0m0.097s
```

yes it took full 7 minutes !!

heres my setup detail

```
(env1) [centos@linux1 ~]$ python -V
Python 3.6.8
(env1) [centos@linux1 ~]$ pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------
ansible      2.8.0
asn1crypto   0.24.0
cffi         1.12.3
cryptography 2.6.1
Jinja2       2.10.1
MarkupSafe   1.1.1
pip          19.1.1
pycparser    2.19
PyYAML       5.1
setuptools   40.6.2
six          1.12.0
(env1) [centos@linux1 ~]$ which  ansible
~/env1/bin/ansible
```

any pointers would be of great help, Thanks

Comment: The user and system times (giving the time spent on processor) are quite similar on both runs which makes me think ansible process was simply waiting for the next execution slot on processor. Anything else running on this machine which would load the processor ? Is this a VM that could be dependent on high load on the host system ?

Comment: @Zeitounator  it is a VM, while the command was being executed i did check for steal CPU column in top which was 0 the whole time

Comment: also i found out the PID of the process and its state while it was running
state is in S+

     `(env1) [centos@linux1 ~]$ pgrep -l  ansible
26457 ansible
   (env1) [centos@linux1 ~]$ ps -fp 26457 26263
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
centos   26263 26262  0 14:49 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
centos   26457 26263  2 17:55 pts/1    S+     0:01 /home/centos/env1/bin/python3 /home/centos/env1/bin/ansible --version`